# Kusto: Does projecting or filtering save more time?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

For Kusto queries on very large tables, which of the following saves more time: (A) `project`ing to only keep columns of relevant data first, or using `where` to filter out rows first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do both and the order does not matter since the query optimizer will arrange it in the most optimal way.

As a side note, if your query summarizes the data, then there is no need for an explicit project, only relevant columns will be used.